# How to mock a method that is called from another method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermock, powermockito

The scenario that I'm in

```
public class SecondClass{

    SecondClass(FirstClass fc){
    ...
    }

    public void foo(String a,String b){
        ....
    }
}

public class FirstClass{
    private SecondClass sc;
    public void init(){
        sc = new SecondClass(this);
    }

    public void bar(List<Integer> input){
        .....
        sc.foo(s1,s2);
    }
}
```

I want to get a hold of the String arguments a and b coming into foo. The test class looks as below

```
@PrepareForTest({ FirstClass.class, SecondClass.class })
public class SampleTest
{
    private String[] texts;

    @Test
    public void testBar() throws Exception
    {
        texts = new String[2];

        final FirstClass fc = mock(FirstClass.class);
        final SecondClass sc = spy(new SecondClass(fc));

        doAnswer(invocation -> {
            texts = (String[]) invocation.getArguments();
            return null;
        }).when(sc).foo(anyString(), anyString());

        final List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
        input.add(1);
        fc.bar(input);

        System.out.println(texts[0]+"<>"+text[1]);
    }
}
```

The sysout at the end prints null<>null. Why is the texts array not getting updated?

Comment: 1/ `sc` is a local var in `SecondClass`, so your code is not valid (`sc` is undefined in `bar`) 2/ In your test you have a `sc` that is a spy **but** this `sc` is not the one used in `bar` (see also 1/)

Comment: And WHAT do you want to test? The functionality of FirstClass? Why mock that then?

Comment: @RC I updated the code as per your point 1.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz I wan't to test the string s1 and s2 passed from bar. If I can achieve the same without using/calling sc in my test then I will go that route, but not sure how to.

Comment: Use a real `FirstClass`, a `SecondClass` mock you somehow "inject" (setter, constructor, reflection) and that should do.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is that `FirstClass` initialises its own copy of `SecondClass`, whereas you want to provide a mock or similar.

The *inversion of control* or *dependency injection* approach is designed to mitigate such situations, by giving classes the components they need in order to operate. Can you instead *inject* a copy of `SecondClass` into `FirstClass` instead (e.g. via a parameter to `init()`) ? That way, you can provide your mock during your test scenario and consequently test your method invocation.

e.g.

```
FirstClass fc = new FirstClass();
fc.init(myMockedSecondClass);
fc.bar(...);

// now test the invocations on your mock
```

Comment: that's not an option in my case. I want to test the string s1 and s2 that are generated by the bar method. If its possible to do that without creating an sc object then I will choose that route. I'm not sure how to without using sc as s1 and s2 are local variables inside bar.

Comment: You call a method on your mock with s1 and s2. So you can assert that that method is called with *particular* values. This does solve your problem

Comment: well s1 and s2 are generated based on the list of integers that I pass. I want to test that the correct s1 and s2 string are generated. eg: input to bar is a list containing 1 then s1 = "single digit" and s2 = "positive". if the input to bar is say -34 then s1 = "double digit" and s2 = "negative". Does this help?

Comment: Well, if you use the verify() method in Mockito (for example - whatever mock framework you use will provide a similar function) then you can test this. It's a similar invocation to what you're doing above, except you replace anyString() with a check for your required string (IIRC)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this...

```
public void init(){
   SecondClass sc = new SecondClass(this);
}
```

with a Setter for `sc`, then put a Mock there in your testcase, thus enabling you to test the real `bar` method of `FirstClass`.